# TextureView.getBitmap() showing inconsistent performance

Tags: android, performance, video, image-processing

I'm doing some image processing tests with Bitmap images obtained from a TextureView, which is handling my video input. In my test I've noticed that the time TextureView.getBitmap(Bitmap) takes to run, sometimes varies between executions.

To demonstrate the problem I modified a sample from the TextureView API [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html). In the code below, I use the camera as input to the  TextureView, grab the bitmap and render it to a SurfaceView, measuring how much time it takes. I've tested it on a pair of Nexus 7 devices both running Android 4.2.2. I've actually noticed two patterns, a slow one and a fast one.

When the execution is “slow”, getBitmap(Bitmap) takes about 20ms.
When the execution is “fast”, getBitmap(Bitmap) takes about 15ms.

Most of the time this the app runs in “slow” mode. If I fiddle with the device or recompile/reinstall the app, sometimes I get it to work in “fast” mode. But after that it will run in slowly again. The speed only changes after the program is restarted, never during execution.

By the way, dumping the Bitmap to the SurfaceView only takes around 8ms: I wonder why getting the Bitmap out of the TextureView takes more than double that time.

The questions:

1. Why does this disparity in execution time happen?
2. Is there a way to ensure that getBitmap(Bitmap) always runs as fast
   as possible?
3. Is it reasonable that writing to SurfaceView be twice faster than
   reading from TextureView?

Thank you.

--Rafael

PS: I've already posted this in Android Developers Google Group, but it seems it is stuck in moderation since last week. Sorry for cross posting.

Edit:

I've added a [sample project](https://github.com/rafosierra/android/tree/master/TextureView_getBitmap_test1) to GitHub for those who wish to try it more easily:

The activity:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.TextureView;

public class LiveCameraActivity extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;

    private final int imgW = 640;
    private final int imgH = 480;
    private Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgW, imgH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    private Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();

        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureview);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

        final int textSize = 24;
        paint1.setColor(0xff00ffff);
        paint1.setTextSize(textSize);

    }

    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.getNumberOfCameras()-1);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(imgW, imgH);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Something bad happened
        }
    }

    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        // Ignored, Camera does all the work for us
    }

    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        return true;
    }

    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        // Invoked every time there's a new Camera preview frame
        long time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        mTextureView.getBitmap(bmp);

        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - time0;

        final Canvas c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if ( c != null) {
            canvas.drawText("getBmp= "  + time1, 10, 40, paint1);
            c.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
        long total = System.currentTimeMillis() - time0;
        long time2 = total -time1;
        Log.i("onFrame", "timing: getBmp= "  + time1 + " blit= " + time2 + " total= " + total);
    }
}
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="640px"
        android:layout_height="480px" />

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureview"
        android:layout_width="640px"
        android:layout_height="480px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm seeing similar performance or worse on my Nexus 10. Is there any way to get the bitmap faster?

Comment: Did you get any further? What about pre-allocating the image in a scaled Bitmap and use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) ?

Comment: I guess there is no fix for it.Try going native,i mean using **libuvc** or **v4l** library.Right now I am also trying on that.